# How do you add Mime types to MimetypesFileTypeMap?

Tags: java, mime-types

hen trying to check what file type my favicon.ico file is,  `MimetypesFileTypeMap` returns `application/octet-stream` even if it's an .ico file.

I've tried using the `addMimeTypes()` but it gives me a compiling error.  The code I'm using is:

```
MimetypesFileTypeMap mimeMap = new MimetypesFileTypeMap();
mimeMap=mimeMap.addMimeTypes("ico");
fileType =mimeMap.getContentType(fileName);
```

which returns this error in the compiler

> ```
> WebWorker.java:95: error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted
> to MimetypesFileTypeMap
>      mimeMap=mimeMap.addMimeTypes("ico");
> ```

Reasons why I used `addMimeTypes` is because of [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/activation/MimetypesFileTypeMap.html).

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue this way

```
 if (fileName.endsWith(".ico")) {
        fileType = "image/x-icon";
      } else {
        MimetypesFileTypeMap mimeMap = new MimetypesFileTypeMap();
        fileType = mimeMap.getContentType(fileName);
      }
```